# Inclusion of skeleton into CW complex gives isomorphism in relative homology

Tags: homology-cohomology, cw-complexes

This question is actually formulated for cohomology but I think the proof will be dual.

Let $H_\bullet$ be a general homology theory satisfying dimension axiom and union axiom. Let $(X,A)$ be a relative CW-complex, and let $X_k$ be its $k$-skeleton. Show that the inclusion $(X_k,A) \hookrightarrow (X,A)$ induces an isomorphism $H_n(X_k,A) \to H_n(X,A)$ if $n<k$.

---

Here my thoughts. One usually considers the long exact sequence of the triple $(X,X_k,A)$:
$$
\cdots \to H_n(X,X_k) \to H_n(X_k,A) \to H_n(X,A) \to H_{n-1}(X,X_k) \to \cdots.
$$
The question is whether the outer terms are zero if $n<k$. This is simple enough if $X = X_{k+1}$. In this case, one can use excision. But what if $X$ is **infinite-dimensional**? If I can somehow show by induction that $H_n(X_l,X_k) = 0$ for $l>k$, then one surely could use some direct limit argument to conclude for the whole space $X$.

---

**Update** @Lee Mosher: The thing is that $X_{k+1} \setminus X_k$ is fairly simple, namely a bunch of open $(k+1)$-cells. Pick for each open $(k+1)$-cell $e_i$ some point $x_i$ in $e_i$. Then
$$
H_n(X_{k+1}, X_k) \cong H_n(X_{k+1}, X_{k+1} \setminus \{x_i \mid i \in I\}) \cong H_n(\coprod_i e_i, \coprod_i (e_i \setminus \{x_i\})) \cong \bigoplus_i H_n(D^{k+1}, S^k).
$$
Using a long exact sequence argument on the triple $(D^{k+1},S^k,*)$ and using relative homology, i.e. $H_\bullet(D^{k+1},*) = 0$ and $H_n(S^k,*) = \delta_{nk} H_0(*)$ (this is the Kroneker delta), shows that $H_n(D^{k+1}, S^k)$ is isomorphic to $H_0(*)$ if $n=k+1$ and zero everywhere else.

Comment: Perhaps you can could add some details to explain how you use finite dimensionality in your excision proof for the case $X=X_{k+1}$.

Comment: @LeeMosher I added details.